# Is the tag order relevant for valid XML?

Tags: xml, validation, tags

in other words:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <tag1>
  <tag1.1></tag1.1>
 </tag1>
 <tag2 />
<root>
```

is the same as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
     <tag2 />
     <tag1>
      <tag1.1></tag1.1>
     </tag1>     
    <root>
```

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In as much detail as they are shown, your two examples are semantically the same.

It's a common misunderstanding of XML that in a well-formed XML document the order of sibling elements is significant. The [XML 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) specifies that attributes are unordered, however it says nothing about elements. Therefore an XML processor is free to report element siblings in any order it likes.

That said, I don't think any commonly used XML processors report elements in a different order to the order they appear in a document.

You ask about a 'valid' document – this implies that a DTD or schema is in use, and therefore it may (or may not) be the case that the order is relevant. There are mechanisms for a DTD or schema to specify that element order is relevant within a document. However, your examples don't show use of a DTD or schema.

Comment: In fact there is a DTD. Thanks.

Comment: "It's a common misunderstanding of XML that in a well-formed XML document the order of elements is significant."  It's no misunderstanding.  See 3.2.1.  Of course, an XML processor could be capable of processing the sequence constraint and still return elements in a different order.  It could rot13 all the text nodes, too.

Comment: @Robert Rossney - I've edited to change to "sibling elements", however, I don't see the relevance of 3.2.1 to ordering of sibling elements in a well-formed document. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The existence of the sequence constraint implies that element ordering is significant.  In fact the ordering of all information in an XML document is significant *except* attributes, and that's because the recommendation explicitly calls that ordering out as insignificant.

Comment: I think the constraint is for validity, not well-formedness. There's nothing explicit in the spec about element ordering in well-formed documents. Surely, we're not supposed to take implications from a spec - they're supposed to be explicit, aren't they? Especially on such fundamental concepts as this.

Answer (score 5):

It is not important for XML itself. Both documents are of course **well-formed** XML documents. However, they may not be **valid**; when validating with an XML Schema, it is possible to specify an order, and not providing the elements in that order will make the document invalid according to the schema. This can be done with the `xsd:sequence` element as described [here](http://www.xmlschemareference.com/sequenceElement.html)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the DTD (or schema) of your language definition.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what is consuming the XML.  The order of the elements may not be important in terms of the XML document being well formed (depending on the XSD), but certain programs / APIs expect to read the XML in alphabetical order (such as the DataContractSerializer in .NET).

Also, the order might be semantically important (e.g. if the XML is representing a document, order is very important).

Comment: I'd make the distinction between *valid* (i.e. conforms to some DTD/schema) and *well-formed* (i.e. is syntactically legal XML) more explicit.  Right now I'd be tempted to say this argument is incorrect due to the way it uses the word "valid".

Comment: @Andrzej - good point.  I updated my answer to use well-formed instead of valid.

Comment: The order of the elements will *never* be important in terms of it being well formed and XSDs have nothing to do with well formed ness.

Comment: @David - that's what I thought until I looked at Jonas H's anshwer.

Comment: –— That answer says that an XSD can specify order and that not following said order would make the document invalid. It also says that the document would still be well formed. (Which is what I said)

Answer (score 0):

XML maintains an order of documents - those are considered two different documents.

Your application may or may not consider the order of elements to be important. For example, the order of elements is essential in XHTML. If you are validating against a Schema or similar, it depends on the schema whether or not both documents are valid.

Note that the order of attributes is not important however (XML documents that differ only in the order of attributes on elements are considered identical).